# Mysql json docs select

Tags: mysql, json

```json
[
    {
        "activity_id": 8,
        "sub_activity_name": "sub801",
        "activity_completed": 0
    },
    {
        "activity_id": 8,
        "sub_activity_name": "sub802",
        "activity_completed": 0
    },
    {
        "activity_id": 10,
        "sub_activity_name": "sub1001",
        "activity_completed": 0
    },
    {
        "activity_id": 10,
        "sub_activity_name": "sub1002",
        "activity_completed": 0
    }
]
```

I want to query this json like

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(sub_activity,'$[*]') 
  FROM t1 
  WHERE sub_activity ->> '$.activity_id' = 8;
```

to get a result like this:

```json
{
    "activity_id": 8,
    "sub_activity_name": "sub801",
    "activity_completed": 0
},
{
    "activity_id": 8,
    "sub_activity_name": "sub802",
    "activity_completed": 0
}
```

also what to set
activity_completed : 1
where activity_id = 10 and sub_activity_name = sub1001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to get a result like this

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(jsontable.element) filtered
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.value,
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (element JSON PATH '$')) jsontable
WHERE jsontable.element->'$.activity_id' = 8 ;
```

> set activity_completed : 1 where activity_id = 10 and sub_activity_name = sub1001

```sql
UPDATE test
CROSS JOIN (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG( CASE WHEN jsontable.element->'$.activity_id' = 10
                                        AND jsontable.element->>'$.sub_activity_name' = 'sub1001'
                                  THEN CAST( '{"activity_id": 10,                   
                                               "sub_activity_name": "sub1001",
                                               "activity_completed": 1}' AS JSON) 
                                  ELSE jsontable.element END ) value
            FROM test
            CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(test.value,
                                  '$[*]' COLUMNS (element JSON PATH '$')) jsontable) data
SET test.value = data.value;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34c18bcab29de3b5eea2e22573079aa0

PS. Of course for a group of rows the 2nd query must use `INNER JOIN .. USING (test.id)`.